# Absolute cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-2010, absolute

I have

A1: `100`

A5: `=$A$1`

What I want is cell A5 to ALWAYS look into cell A1 regardless of what happens. So if I insert a row above A1, I still want A5 to be looking at A1.

I thought using an absolute cell reference would do this but apparently not.

Every time I insert a row, excel does what it is supposed to do and changes A5 to `=$A$2`

Anyway to stop this?

Comment: I hope you don't mind I edited your question to use absolute references in your formulas as you say you are already using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following volatile formula (it will be recalculated after any change, which might affect performance if you have too many of them):

```
=INDIRECT("A1")
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("A1:A4"))
```

Or a normal formula which might be slightly less readable:

```
=INDEX(A:A,1)
```

Comment: @pnuts true, but with your line of thinking you could insert only 3 new lines above A1 which would not make much sense, so I agree it's not clear what is the OP's intention exactly..

Comment: Thank you!   The indirect works well for 1 cell. How would I do it if I wanted to use a counta function with that over a range?

Comment: My intention is every month to add 150 new rows(macro). I have a yearly and monthly totals table on a different sheet. The yearly results are easy enough, but I want the monthly results to always be counting in the same range.

Comment: I added an example for `counta` - not sure if possible with non-volatile formula though...

Comment: are you asking something in the last comment? if yes, please try to be more specific..

Comment: =COUNTA(INDIRECT("A2:A3")) appears to be working. Once I start adding more data each month it will prove itself true or not!

Answer (score -1):

for absolute reference , press F4

as you are saying , A1=100

when you enter the row above A1, the position of A1 is updated. if you want the new A1, use macro . and select cell A1